# How do I make Thunderbird 17.0 stop notifying me with junk mail?

Tags: thunderbird, email

I use a few email accounts with one dedicated to junk and spam. Thunderbird is auto tagging them as spam/junk, but still displays them as unread mail. It's not wrong, but it makes the pop up and unread counter kind of useless as I don't know how much new mail I actually have!

I want Thunderbird to not count junk mail as unread messages and not to notify me of them.

**Ubuntu 12.10, Thunderbird 17.0.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit->Preferences->Security Tab->**

There is a checkbox:

"Mark messages determined to be Junk as read"

[image]

Comment: this is not only applicable for ubuntu of course